# Denominator for the Labor Force Participation By group

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, nonexpert

I want to check that I am using the correct definition for labor force participation rates by gender or income group. For instance, if we have the following:

1- Working age population of 800 people, with 400 men and 400 women
2- Total workforce of 500 individuals, with 300 men and 200 women.

Would the LFP rate for women be 200 in the workforce/800 total working age population?

Or 200 women in the workforce/ 400 working age women?

I have seen both used, but I assume only the second denominator is correct?

Comment: The second choice.  You want the number of the group of interest participating divided by the total number of the group of interest

Comment: Thanks for the verification!